# pip3 - Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)

Tags: python, django, pip

I created a virtualenv:

```
mkvirtualenv someenv
```

It is automatically activated and I tried to install django

```
pip3 install django
```

and it says:

```
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)
```

Am I missing some configuration? How to fix this?

Comment: What do you see on your command prompt? Did it change (e.g. did `(someenv)` appear at the start)?

Comment: yes it appears. I even deactivated and reactivated just in case.